# PHP - Error in IMAP command STORE: Invalid messageset

Tags: php, imap

I'm using imap with php and I found this error:

**Unknown: IMAP protocol error: Error in IMAP command STORE: Invalid messageset (0.001 + 0.000 secs). (errflg=2)**

This happens only with some mailboxes (ex. one hosted on misterdomain.eu).

The error occurs at the end of the script, after **imap_close()**.

This is the simple code. If you have any suggest (far to my first problem), is really accepted.

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SINCE "'.date("d-M-y",strtotime("-3 days")).'"',SE_UID);

if($emails) {
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        echo "<h1>".$email_number."</h1>";
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number, FT_UID);

        if($overview[0]->seen)
            imap_clearflag_full($inbox,$email_number,"//Seen");
        else
            imap_clearflag_full($inbox,$email_number,"//Unseen");

        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number, FT_UID);

        if(isset($structure->parts)){
            $flattenedParts = flattenParts($structure->parts);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($flattenedParts);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "</br>";           
            getmsg($inbox, $email_number);

            echo "<p>".htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode($plainmsg))."</p>";
        }else{
            $string_email = utf8_decode(imap_body($inbox, $email_number, FT_UID));
            $string_email= strip_tags($string_email);
            $string_email = html_entity_decode($string_email,ENT_QUOTES);
            echo "<p>".$string_email."</p>";
        }

    }
} 
imap_close($inbox);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching and fetching using UIDs, but storing using message sequence numbers.  These ways of numbering the messages don't match, so you are sending invalid message numbers to store.  Add the approriate ST_UID flag to imap_clearflag_full.

Also, the system flags use *backslashes*, not forward slashes: `'\\Seen'`.
`\Unseen` isn't a defined flag.  You probably want to *add* the `\Seen` flag instead.

Comment: Really thx! So if i read an "unread" mail, it remain as "unread"?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish with setting/clearing flags.  The flags shouldn't change, as long as you're using the PEEK variants of the fetch functions.

Comment: Ok, it's clear. I don't want to change the "seen" status (let unread if it was unread before). Thanks a lot!